# scala: futures and lists

Tags: list, scala, future, for-comprehension

I have such methods

```
def jobs: Future[List[Job]]
def jobTasks(jobId: Int): Future[List[Task]]
```

Object *Job* has *jobId*  field.

I need to collect all jobs with all tasks, which match to job to `List[JobWithTasks]`

```
case class JobWithTasks(job: Job, tasks: List[Task])
```

Tried Future.traverse, some cats methods within for comprehensions. No result.

Comment: It's not clear to me what you want to do. Can you provide a sample input and output?

Comment: @mfirry thanks for a will to help.
Luis Miguel Mejía Suárez has alredy generalized my thoughts.
I rewrite his solution in for comrehension with parTraverse. Everything is good.
Code is pretty simple, it is strange that I got stuck yesterday.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If we have one **Job** we only need to call `jobTasks` and then `map` that future to get a single **JobWithTasks**.

If we have a **List** of **Jobs**, we can use `traverse` to apply the previous process to each **Job** and the return a single **Future** of **List** of **JobWithTasks**.

Finally, if we have a **Future** of a **List** of **Jobs**, we need to use `flatMap` to apply the previous procedure to get a single **Future** of **List** of **JobWithTasks**.

So, the code looks like this:

```
def jobsWithTaks: Future[List[JobWithTasks]] =
  jobs.flatMap { listOfJobs =>
    Future.traverse(listOfJobs) { job =>
      jobTasks(jobId = job.id).map { listOfTasks =>
        JobWithTasks(job, listOfTasks)
      }
    }
  }
```

This is a process called [**type tetris**](https://underscore.io/blog/posts/2017/04/11/type-tetris.html) which is very useful for expressive and functional languages like Scala.